# sending and receiving emoticons to webservice

Tags: android, web-services, emoji

I have implemented the https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon lib for emoticons and emoticons get displayed in the edit text. Now I have edit text that takes in both text and emoticons. I want the text/emoticons entered in the edit text to be sent to the web service. when I just say get text from that edit text I can see only '??' of the emoticons on the server.I know i got to convert the emoticon to Unicode and then send it but I don't know how to implement it and also how to decode only the emoticons in the edit text. Please help me.

I just get the text from the edit text and save it in a 'userstatus' string and pass it to json as

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

         Log.d("userstatus",userstatus);

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("my_status",userstatus));
         params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",userid));






          try{
              // getting JSON string from URL
               JSONObject json3 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_updateprofilestatus, "POST", params);
```

**My json class**

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Emoticons are nothing but special sequence of text which refer to some emoticons on your device. While sending emoticons you don't actually send the emoticons but a sequence of text character which is associated with it. Once the device receives it, it replaces that particular text with the right emoticons (image). Like (^) is equivalent to cake emoticons in Skype.

Comment: how will i send these special sequence of characters to the server? i learnt that the emoticons need to be converted to unicode characters. how do i do that?

Comment: If you use the POST parameter for sending your data to your server you won't encounter the problem of uni-coding.

Comment: i use post only but still the emoticons are displayed as question marks.Please help me

Comment: i have posted my json class above..plz help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by adding in the POST method

Make sure that in the Logger you get question marks with a black background to make sure that's a emoticon

Then add:

```
 if (json != null) 
 {
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, "UTF-8"));
 }
```